# Fields on form blank after viewing web link

Tags: cognito-forms

I have put a web link in a form.  When someone clicks on the link to view the website and clicks the "back" arrow, it will go back to the form but all of the fields that were previously filled out are blank.

How can someone get back to the form and pick up where they left off?

Answer (score 1):

The assumption is that you are talking about a webpage that has form inputs.
In your "a" tag put `target="_blank"`. This will pop the link's location up in a new window. Then to get back you close the window. If you have control of the webpage the link points to, then put a <kbd>close</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd> button on the webpage that pops up.